# Strange behaviour of bootstrap alert when showing it with sliding animation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to show a Bootstrap Alert Box, by sliding it down. The sliding animation works as intended, but it seems like the bottom padding of the alert gets added only when the whole animation is complete.

What could be the problem, or a possible solution to this problem?

This is the javascript code I use for the animation:

```
jQuery("#testDiv").hide().show('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 1500).parent(".ui-effects-wrapper").hide().slideDown(1500);
```

I've set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate this strange behaviour:

> http://jsfiddle.net/dg6xh5m0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's happening with styles, but when you use wrapper for it then it works. Have a look here:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/dg6xh5m0/2/`
```

Comment: strange, but you are right. this solves my problem, so I will mark it as correct until (if) someone comes up with a better answer, that can explain the strange behaviour of the css:) thanks:)

Comment: No worries, hope someone will provide better explanation. I'm curious why is this happening too :)